# How to get width of first level list elements with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, list, each

I have this markup:

```
<div class="cntr">
  <ul>
      <li class="frst_lvl" style="width: 125px;">
         <ul>
           <li class="scnd_lvl" style="width: 25px;"></li>
           <li class="scnd_lvl" style="width: 25px;"></li>
           <li class="scnd_lvl" style="width: 25px;"></li>
         </ul>
      </li>
      <li class="frst_lvl" style="width: 125px;"></li>
      <li class="frst_lvl" style="width: 125px;"></li>
      <li class="frst_lvl" style="width: 125px;"></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

I need to get combine width of all elements with class `frst_lvl`. I use this function but `.each()` method gets the width of all elements, even those of the second degree - `scnd_lvl`. How to write this correctly?

```
var t = 0,
    $cntr = $('.cntr'),
    $list = $cntr.find('> ul'),
    $list_el = $list.find('> li');

function listWidth() {
    var total = t;
    $list_el.each(function() {
        total += parseInt($(this).width());
    });
    return total;
}
$list.width(listWidth());
```

Thx, for help.

Comment: `$list_el.length` is 4 or 7?

Comment: wird but in console i have 4

Comment: You need to close your `<li>`s, they don't auto close.

Comment: this is write mistake

Comment: @Zeaklous i need to do this without any classes, this is only for this example

Comment: I mean you have to close the other `li` elements, you only fixed more. If your code is like this in your project then that's an issue

Comment: Why do you need to do this without classes? You already seem to *have* classes in your HTML.

Comment: @Zeaklous Closing `LI` (and number of other tags) is optional.

Comment: Still this is write mistake

Comment: Your function works correctly. `listWidth()` returns 500, which is combined width of four outer LIs.

Answer (score 0):

This will give you the combined width of all elements with class `frst_lvl`

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    $width = 0;
    $( ".frst_lvl").each(function( index ) {
        $width += parseFloat($(this).width());
    }); alert($width);
});
```

Answer (score -1):

$.find will give you back every descendant that match. In your example $list contains two list and $list_el contains 7 items.

Use $.children method instead. That travels only a single level down in the DOM

$list = $cntr.children('> ul'),
    $list_el = $list.children('> li');

see the docs here: http://api.jquery.com/children/

Comment: When you prefix the selector with ` > `, it will only match the immediate descendants. Example [here](http://jsfiddle.net/8gsrX/)